# gzsdf problem INstalling GAZEBO 4 under ROS Indigo

Tags: gazebo-4, ros-indigo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I have just realize that after installing gazebo4 under ros indigo with the package (that I don't remember the name) I can not call anymore gzsdf in the terminal. Is it not anymore available?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7124/gzsdf-problem-installing-gazebo-4-under-ros-indigo/) by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Solved. In Gazebo 4 is

```
gz sdf --print
```

---

Originally posted by [Enrico Mingo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/507/enrico-mingo/) with karma: 121 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1